# Unable to upload Cordova code to MFP version 8 with mfpdev command -

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have imstall IBM MFP 8 on a Ubuntu server with Tomcat 8.

I have configured mfpdev on my local machine and have access to the MFP server. However, I get the follwoing errors when I tried to register my code to the MFP server.
Can you please let me know how to fix this issue.

command = mfpdev -d app register qamobilegcpmfp1  mfp

Result =

```
    mfpdev-cli verb cli process.argv=["/usr/local/bin/node","/usr/local/bin/mfpdev","-d","app","register","qamobilegcpmfp1","mfp"]
    mfpdev-cli verb cli opts={"debug":true,"argv":{"remain":["app","register","qamobilegcpmfp1","mfp"],"cooked":["--debug","app","register","qamobilegcpmfp1","mfp"],"original":["-d","app","register","qamobilegcpmfp1","mfp"]}}
    mfpdev-cli verb cli mobilefirst@8.0.0
    mfpdev-cli verb cli node@v6.9.5
    Verifying server configuration...
    mfpdev-cli verb getRuntimes processResp: success
    Registering to server:'http://172.16.001.99:3100' runtime:'mfp'
    mfpdev-cli verb detectPlatforms detecting platforms present
    mfpdev-cli verb parsePlatformInfo Parsing platform: cordova-android
    mfpdev-cli verb mfp-config-xml Initializing get, set, and delete methods.
    Updated config.xml file located at: /Users/Douments/Development/mymobile/dev/MobileV2/config.xml
    Run 'cordova prepare' to propagate changes.
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody processResp: OK(200) failure: {
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody   "jse_shortmsg": "Server request was unsuccessful. Check your server's availability or contact IBM Support.",
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody   "jse_summary": "Server request was unsuccessful. Check your server's availability or contact IBM Support.: FWLSE0323: State change failure: HTTP 200 - OK",
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody   "jse_cause": {
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     "jse_shortmsg": "FWLSE0323: State change failure",
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     "jse_summary": "FWLSE0323: State change failure: HTTP 200 - OK",
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     "jse_cause": {
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody       "name": "OK"
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     },
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     "message": "FWLSE0323: State change failure: HTTP 200 - OK",
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody     "name": "FAILURE"
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody   },
    mfpdev-cli verb postRawBody   "message": "Server request was unsuccessful. Check your server's availability or contact IBM Support.: FWLSE0323: State change failure: HTTP 200 - OK",
  "java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:3100/mfpadminconfig/api/schema/mfp_default_schema/1.0/configuration/21be5c1b-c988-4af3-b32e-d5ca0895574f?dataOnly=true"
```

Comment: Please use node version 6.11.1

Comment: Error says java.io.FileNotFoundException at http://localhost:3100/mfpadminconfig/api/schema/mfp_default_schema/1.0/configuration/ see if it is exists there